# Append data with concat that does not already exist mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there an easy way to only append data to an existing column if it does not exist?

**My code**

```
UPDATE table SET read_test = concat(read_test, '|string|') WHERE ID = '000'
```

Comment: You can use an IF statement to check first before you concat.

Comment: Trying to avoid using another connection to the database

Comment: Do you mean it should not exist in `read_test` of that specific row, or anyway in your table? Might `... WHERE ID = '000' and not read_test like '%|string|%'` do what you want?

Comment: omg I didn't even think of that, I'm an idiot. I just need to add `AND read_test NOT LIKE '|%string%|'`. Thanks man